# Android media player loop without gap (without silent sound while song beginning and ending)

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, soundpool

I am new to Android development, am doing the concept for playing short audio file in a loop without gab, I read many Stack Overflow questions and tried that too but I am not able to achieve it. But the concept is possible, I saw many application is available in store and its working fine, I really don't know how they did.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ipnossoft.rma.free&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.relaxio.sleepo&hl=en

I checked those application they used short audio with OGG format.

And they can able to play multiple audio at the same time without gap.

Is there any other library or framework available? to do this in Android.

Note: I tried [this framework](https://github.com/huhx0015/HXAudioPlayer) but no luck. It support only one audio file to play in loop but it's not working good.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Soundpool . Even I had the same problem in mediaplyer and the solution is soundpool
Here is a [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-soundpool-example/) to get the idea of how to use soundpool

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @WhatsThePoint .I am new to Stack Overflow .I'll keep in mind the next time I answer any question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a built in android lib called **SoundPool** to use import

```java
import android.media.SoundPool;
```

then initialize by

```java
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {        
   public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
    //DO SOMETHING WHEN MEDIA HAS LOADED HERE
}});
  soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.loop, 1);
```

Important to note that a global variable named **soundID** or any other name should be found in the class and audio R.raw.loop or any other name should exist.

To play or pause Loop use this

```java
void playSound() throws Exception{
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float volume= audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)/audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, -1, 1f);
    }
void pauseSound() throws Exception{
        soundPool.pause(soundID);
    }
```